# withTrashed() failed after updating to 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

After updating to 4.2 using composer update, I have added

```
use SoftDeletingTrait;  
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

to User model. Here is the code use this model:

`$users = User::withTrashed()->paginate(20);`

But when I run application, it shows following error message:

> Undefined index: User
>   at \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php 346

I tried to change to

```
$users = User::all();
```

and everything is OK. So how could I solve this?

Comment: I have solved this problem. It is because I overwrite model's constructor but did not invoke parent's. After I add `parent::__construct()`, everything is OK.

Comment: You might want to add that as an actual answer to the question.

Comment: I had a similar issue with this.  I did not override `__construct` - it turns out if you set the static `boot` method you also need to call: `parent::boot();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem maybe because if you had overwrite models' constructors but didnot invoke parents'. So add `parent::__constructor()` in your own models' constructors. Also, @Ash has metioned if you set the static `boot` method, you also need to call `parent::boot()`.